# No ActionBar appearing in my EditFriendsActivity. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'm developing a chat app based on the tutorial on teamtreehouse.com

After writing all the code in EditFriendsActivity.java file, I ran the app & I noticed that there is no ActionBar in the Edit Friends Activity.

On the contrary, ActionBar is appearing on rest of the activities!

What could have gone wrong here?

**EditFriendsActivity.java:**

```
public class EditFriendsActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static final String TAG = EditFriendsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;
    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_friends);

        getActionBar();

        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        mFriendsRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.orderByAscending(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);
        query.setLimit(1000);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // Success!
                    mUsers = users;
                    String[] usernames = new String[mUsers.size()];
                    int i = 0;
                    for (ParseUser user : mUsers) {
                        usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                        i++;
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            EditFriendsActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
                            usernames);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                    addFriendCheckmarks();
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditFriendsActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.error_title);
                    builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        if (getListView().isItemChecked(position)){
            // add friend
            mFriendsRelation.add(mUsers.get(position));
        } else {
            // remove friend
            mFriendsRelation.remove(mUsers.get(position));
        }
        mCurrentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       /// -- menu ---///
    }

    private void addFriendCheckmarks() {
        mFriendsRelation.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // list returned - look for a match
                    for (int i = 0; i < mUsers.size(); i++) {
                        ParseUser user = mUsers.get(i);

                        for (ParseUser friend: friends) {
                            if (friend.getObjectId().equals(user.getObjectId()));
                            getListView().setItemChecked(i, true);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hammadnasir.ribbit" >

    <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".RibbitApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
            android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditFriendsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_friends"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.hammadnasir.ribbit.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChooseFriendsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_friends"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.hammadnasir.ribbit.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me figure out this.

Comment: Do your other Activities extend ActionBarActivity?

Comment: @Ascorbin No, they extends AppCombatActivity.

Comment: But your this activity is not extending AppCompatActivity...extend it and it will work

Comment: @EEJ After extending AppCompatActivity in this file, I'm getting errors on these lines:
`getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);`,
`setListAdapter(adapter);`,
`super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);`,
`if (getListView().isItemChecked(position)){`,
`getListView().setItemChecked(i, true);`

Now??

Answer (score 1):

After extending `AppCompatActivity`, you should add a `ListView` (or `RecyclerView`) in you `layout.xml` and then implement the code for populating and manipulating the  objects in the corresponding adapter.

When you do not extend `ActionBarActivity`or `AppCompatActivity` you should not get an ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your class file under OnCreate method:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and import this:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```